# Merged array search functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having two data arrays which are coming from API and sample arrays would be like this

Array 1

```
[
{userId: 1
description: "Student"
imagePath: "test.png"
status: 1
}]
```

Array 2

```
[
{id: 85
accountName: "Rahul"
accountNumber: "11145678"
}
]
```

In my reactnative app view there's search bar and user should be able to search from these two arrays. So I merged these two arrays into one using

```
this.searchArray =this.filterArray[0].concat(this.filterArray[1])
```

So, my searchArray is a single array with Array1 and Array2 data. sample below

```
[
{userId: 1
description: "Student"
imagePath: "test.png"
status: 1
},
{id: 85
accountName: "Rahul"
accountNumber: "11145678"
}]
```

My search function is below (I need to search from account number or description)

```
    //Search Filter
searchFilter =searchText=>{

    const searchTextData = searchText.toUpperCase();
    const userSearch =  this.searchArray.filter(item => {  

        const itemData = `${item.description && item.description.toUpperCase()} ${item. accountName && item.accountName.toUpperCase()}`;
        return itemData.indexOf(searchTextData) > -1;    
    });
}
```

The search functionality is not working with accountName. It's not getting any results. But if I remove ${item. accountName && item.accountName.toUpperCase()} , then it's working showing data with description. But I need to filter from both

Comment: there's no return statement in `searchFilter` function

Comment: I only added the function in question here..Not added setState and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your array one object can have description or accountNumber so do a check if that exists include it in the itemData variable.

Try doing this

```
searchFilter =searchText=>{
    const searchTextData = searchText.toUpperCase();
    const userSearch =  this.searchArray.filter(item => {  
 const itemData = `${item.hasOwnProperty('description'))?item.description.toUpperCase():''} ${item.hasOwnProperty('accountNumber')?item.accountNumber:''}`;
        return itemData.indexOf(searchTextData) > -1;    
    });
}
```

Comment: if you found the answer mark any one answer as correct.so that users who face the same problem may know the solution

Answer (score 0):

First merge the two objects into one:

```
Object.keys(arr2[0]).forEach(key => {
  arr1[0][key] = arr2[0][key]
})
```

Then create the search function:

```
function searchObject(obj, value){
   return Object.keys(obj).some(key => {
      return obj[key] === value
   })
}
```

```js
let arr1=[{userId:1,description:"Student",imagePath:"test.png",status:1}],arr2=[{id:85,accountName:"Rahul",accountNumber:"11145678"}];

Object.keys(arr2[0]).forEach(key => {
  arr1[0][key] = arr2[0][key]
})

function searchObject(obj, prop, value){
    return obj[prop] === value
}

console.log(searchObject(arr1[0], "accountName", "asdf"))
console.log(searchObject(arr1[0], "accountName", "Rahul"))
```

Comment: Can you describe what I have done wrong.I also merged those two arrays like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918510/merged-array-search-functionality-is-not-working

Comment: @hiranya I'm not exactly sure, but it looks like you merged the two objects separately into a new array, instead of merging the objects themselves together. By merging the objects themselves, it's easier to perform a search.

Comment: I'm having a single array. Is that the issue?